# Missing information when calculating impedance via Blackman's theorem

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, ac, feedback, small-signal

The AC course at my university has an ex-exam question where, in the below circuit, the impedance w.r.t. ground has to be calculated for the rightmost node.

[image: Circuit]

The question asks to *do this using a test source* (on the small-signal equivalent, which I assume makes the current source up top disconnect as it would be set to 0), and then *check work using Blackman's theorem* (presumably also on the small-signal equivalent). Applying a test voltage to the node, I find
$$i_\textrm{test} = g_mv_{gs}=g_mv_{drain} \qquad\textrm{and}\qquad \frac{v_\textrm{test}-v_{drain}}{10\,\rm k\Omega} = i_\textrm{test} \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad Z_\textrm{in}=\frac{v_\textrm{test}}{i_\textrm{test}} = 10\,{\rm k\Omega} + 1/g_{m} = 10.1\,{\rm k\Omega}$$

Now, I was "taught" (there was very poor teaching involved) Blackman's impedance formula as
$$Z_\textrm{in} = Z_\textrm{in}^\textrm{no feedback}\frac{1+RR_\textrm{short}}{1+RR_\textrm{open}}.$$
where all quantities are defined w.r.t. a cut we make in the feedback loop: the first factor is the impedance we need but when there is no more feedback, and the return ratios are each a ratio of the voltage that appears on the non-amplifier-side of the cut when we apply an input voltage to the amplifier-side of the cut.

**However, I can't seem to figure out how to get to that first factor.** When I cut the feedback by separating the gate from the drain, I can get as far as:
$$i_\textrm{test} = g_mv_{gs}=g_mv_{gate} \qquad\textrm{and}\qquad \frac{v_\textrm{test}-v_{drain}}{10\,\rm k\Omega} = i_\textrm{test}$$
... but now my equations stay underdetermined, since I have 4 unknowns (we need the ratio of two, so effectively 3 unknowns) and only 2 equations. It seems to me that the gate or the drain would need to be given a certain voltage to be able to work out the equations, but what voltage? If the gate is 0, clearly, we get $$i_\textrm{test} = g_mv_{gs}=g_mv_{gate} = 0\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad Z_\textrm{in}^\textrm{no feedback} = v_\textrm{test}/i_\textrm{test} = v_\textrm{test}/0 = +\infty$$

The only way that could turn into something approaching a solution is if the denominator is also infinity, which might be the case; for the open circuit, \$Z_{in}\$ is floating, so there is no closed circuit and the current through the transistor would be \$0\$ making \$v_{gs}\$ and hence the gate (weirdly) be forced to \$0\$. That means
$$RR_\textrm{open} = \frac{-v_{drain}}{v_{gate}} = \frac{-v_{drain}}{0} = -\infty.$$
Seeing as to how \$RR_\textrm{short} = g_m\cdot 10\,{\rm k\Omega}\$, that leaves me with
$$Z_\textrm{in} = Z_\textrm{in}^\textrm{no feedback}\frac{1+RR_\textrm{short}}{1+RR_\textrm{open}} = +\infty\cdot\frac{1+g_m\cdot 10\,{\rm k\Omega}}{1-\infty},$$
so it's a dead end for me.

Comment: Is that the "schematic" from an exam paper?

Comment: @Andyaka The schematic is from an archive of exam questions kept updated by two students. Solutions aren't disclosed after exams, and although the two students have solved many of the archived questions, they explicitly indicate that they do not understand either how Blackman works here (if that answers what you were wondering about).

Comment: No, I'm just surprised at how poor the schematic is drawn given that it's from an exam. i.e. crossing nodes that don't connect don't have a node connector (a dot) and nodes that do connect should be less ambiguous i.e. they should connect at two separate dots.

Comment: @Andyaka Good point. I'd say there is definitely a dot in the four-crossing, since otherwise, the impedance is (trivially) infinite since it's just the transistor's gate impedance.